# 2007 ListViewWebPart to 2010 XSLTListViewWebPart

Tags: xslt-list-view-web-part, list-view-web-part

After migrating from SharePoint 2007 to 2010 we found a few issues in the migrated document libraries,  some styles were looking wierd and the biggest problem is that the "Add New Item" button is not visible at the bottom of the list  view, I know that sharepoint uses LisviewWebparts in 2007 and in 2010 uses XSLTListViewWebparts, manual update is out of the question because there  are a lot of document libraries and sites.

My questions is..."Is there anyway to "update" these webparts using Sharepoint Manegement Shell or any other method?"

Thanks!

Comment: Sharepoint Designer aka SPDesigner does exist

Answer (score 2):

For the list view form, deleting and recreating the views worked for me:

```
private static void RebuildView(SPList list, SPView view)
{
    list.Views.Delete(view.ID);
    list.Update();
    string title = view.Title;
    SPView cloneView = view.Clone(
        title.Replace(" ", string.Empty), 
        view.RowLimit, 
        view.Paged, 
        view.DefaultView);
    cloneView.Title = title;
    cloneView.Update();
}
```

I also came across the following regarding changing web parts on other pages:

- [Converting ListViewWebPart to XSLTListViewWebPart on Sharepoint 2010](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/sharepoint2010setup/thread/213e7ad9-8f36-4b54-8ca2-407ecd742325)
- [XsltListViewWebPart – several XSLT tips](http://stefan-stanev-sharepoint-blog.blogspot.com/2010/08/xsltlistviewwebpart-several-xslt-tips.html?showComment=1332079314017#c6723288528526937999)