# enable ajax on listview web part added in feature upgrade

Tags: 2010, ajax, list-view-web-part

is there an option how to enable ajax functionality in `listview` web part type added by code? Iam facing problem where we added 2 list view web parts on the page and they behave really strange. I read article where enabling ajax should fix this behavior however i dont know how to enable the ajax. In public members of list view web part there is not such properties for ajax enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Enable async refresh:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart.asyncrefresh.aspx

You can also set auto refresh and refresh interval to get actual data without page reloading:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart.autorefresh.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart.autorefreshinterval.aspx

Comment: well actualy what you wrote down is true, however ListViewWebPart does not subclass DataFormWebPart

Comment: I thought you tell about XsltListViewWebPart that is derived from DataFormWebPart. You can convert old ListViewWebPart into XsltListViewWebPart: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21951/2007-listviewwebpart-to-2010-xsltlistviewwebpart